# MySQL lithuanian collation

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

When I am trying to return values using php script I am getting null. The null values are variables with lithuanian characters. The problem is that I am using utf-8_lithuanian_ci on the tables variables where lithuanian characters would apear. Am I doing something wrong? Collation of MySQL connection is set also to utf-8_lithuanian_ci

**EDITED:**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","*********","*******");
mysql_select_db("******");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mdl_user ");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the php code you're using? DB connection, selection, output, etc.?

Comment: Output would be standart. What I mean is that where varchar type variable has only english characters is fine. But with lithuanian the output would be null

Comment: `json_encode` will return null if the string is not in UTF-8, so it seems like the data received by your script is not really UTF-8 (which works for english characters only because their representation is the same in latin1 and utf-8). I suspect you need to execute [`SET NAMES utf8`](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) after connecting to the DB. 

Also, `mysql_` functions are being deprecated, you should be using `PDO` or `mysqli_` instead.

Comment: Could you give an example? How to correctly use set names? because I need to get lithuanian chars.

Comment: Call `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` after `mysql_connect`. (And check the return status of all those mysql_ functions, in case of errors).

Comment: Now where lithuanian char should be I am getting \u0160. Is there away now to change it some how in java code?

Comment: That's how extended characters are typically represented in JSON. You don't need to convert it any further, Javascript will read and display it correctly. Try it, enter `alert("\u0160");` in your browser's Javascript console.